# Input field with dynamic attribute saves as undefined, MEAN stack application

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Why is the value for a dynamic attribute saved as "undefined" in my form? I thought it had something to do with hidden input but it does the same thing when it is not hidden.

When saving a new event, I want the user to click an image and for the URL of that image to be saved as a string under img_url. The normal text input "event_name" saves fine. The click function is working fine - it saves the value of img_url when the picture is clicked and I checked this with console logs. It just saves as undefined.

html:

```
<div ng-app="event" ng-controller="eventController">
  <form>
        <input id="event_name" type="text" name="event_name" ng-model="formData.event_name">
    <label for="event_name">Event name</label>
    <p>Choose an image:</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="images"><img src="/images/e1.png"></li>
      <li class="images"><img src="/images/e2.png"></li>
      <li class="images"><img src="/images/e3.png"></li>
    </ul>
    <input id="img_url" name="img_url" type="hidden" ng-model="formData.img_url">
   </form>
 </div>
```

JQuery (in init.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = '';
 $('.images').click(function(){
      url =  $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      $('#img_url').val(url);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are setting the value outside angular's scope, so you need to get scope first then try to assign the value in scope.apply() it like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = '';
 $('.images').click(function(){
      var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=event]');
      var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
      url=$(this).find('img').attr('src');
      $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.formData.img_url = url;
      });


    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! Works a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = '';
$('li').click(function(){
  url =  $('li.images> img').attr('src');
  $('#img_url').val(url);
});
});
```

Try It Once